# How to write bash script to open vi and edit document?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, vi

I'd like to write a bash script that essentially automates this process:

```
vi filename.pdf
```

(open "filename.pdf" using vi)

```
:4,7d
```

(in vi command mode, delete lines 4-7)

```
O
```

(in vi command mode, tap shift+O (captial oh) to create new line)

```
<<>>
```

(in vi insert mode, type two lesser-thans and two greater-thans)

```
ESC
```

(switch vi to command mode)

```
:wq
```

(in vi command mode, save file and quit vi)

```
echo "Complete."
```

Comment: `sed -i '4,7c\<<>>' filename.pdf`

Comment: @Theophrastus. Can you explain why this is "nutzo"?

Comment: @Costas. Thanks! Do you want to post as answer and I mark it as the solution?

Comment: Perhaps you can suggest a better solution. mat (Metadata Anonymisation Toolkit) was recently modified in Debian (https://www.debian.org/security/2016/dsa-3708). I need to be able to remove metadata. When opening recent PDFs I've worked with, the data I need deleted was in lines 4-7 always. this sed thing seems to work. Hopefully MAT will get patched eventually. But until then I need solution. Comments?

Comment: see my answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/848275/how-to-write-bash-script-to-open-vi-and-edit-document/848301#848301

Comment: @Theophrastus. Unfortunately, I'm not as knowledable as you. And this IMO is better than nothing at all. I see what you saying though, but it's all I've found so far that gives me something.

Comment: @Archemar. I don't understand your answer. By contrast Costas' was immediately understandable and worked for me.

Comment: Impossible.  `vi` is a text file editor.  `.pdf` files are **not** text files.

Comment: Probably a duplicate.  In any case, the answers suggested don't use vi *insert mode* as suggested.  You could do this with `expect`.

Answer (score 2):

```
printf '%s\n' '4,7d' a '<<>>' . x | ex filename.txt && echo complete
```

You can't edit PDF files with a text editor, though.

Answer (score 0):

This should automate your process.

```
vim -b -c '4s/.*/<<>>/' -c '5,7d' -c wq filename.pdf
```

## Flag Breakdown

- `-b` binary mode
- `-c {command}` runs the vim automatically when the file is opened.

So `-c '4s/.*/<<>>/' -c '5,7d' -c wq` runs the vim command `4s/.*/<<>>/` followed by `5,7d` followed by a `wq`.